# How to add client certificates and SHA keys to expo applications for API access with Zscaler

Tags: expo, expo-auth-session, expo-permissions, expo-dev-client, expo-publish

I'm using Expo application where I need a certificate to access API calls because I have Zscaler installed on my laptop.

The apk is working once I create it in expo without zscaler, however some device internal users need to use our app with zscaler. Therefore, a certificate needs to be installed before they can use it. i don't want to install a certificate in my device
Is there a way to add certificates to the expo dashboard (java file) ?

There's an application where we're using pure react native and we're adding this certificate directly to the java file itself (cacerts).

I am not sure how to handle the issue in Expo because we can't use local java to build builds. Maybe we need to add this certificate to the code itself in that case, or maybe we need to add permissions to the 'app.json' itself, or we need to add certificates to our environment files or 'app.json' to access different environments. I don't know what to do.